# POST request in Web API C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, asp.net-web-api2

I'm new in working with ASP.net.
I have problem with POST request. Perhaps my code is wrong, I don't find where !

Postman sends me the error message when I try a post request :

"ExceptionType":"System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException","StackTrace":"   à System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   à System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}

Here is my code :

```
// POST: api/Boooks
[Route("~/api/PostCreate")]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] Books books)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest("Invalid data.");
```

Comment: Did you add 'Content-type': 'application/json' header in postman?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error posting JSON to Web API 2 : The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935650/error-posting-json-to-web-api-2-the-request-entitys-media-type-text-plain-i)

Answer (score 0):

If you left it at default, then you will probably find that you need to set the application content type in post man as part of your headers info.

By Default I think asp.net core expects the content type to be of application/json. and your post man call is most likely sending it as text/html.

See your headers sent, make the changes and see the results.

Answer (score 0):

Check your request headers in Postman!

[image: Check your request headers in Postman]

You should not have to change anything in the c# code, it should accept JSON by default.